# Deploy a Spring Boot App with H2 Database on AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, h2

I want to deploy my Java Web Application with an internal H2 database on AWS.
I creates application-prod.properties like:

```
server.port=5000
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./src/main/resources/data/demo
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I package my application as jar and load it up to elastic beanstack. But when I deploy, the database always disappear and I need to recreate the whole schema.
I just want to use the internal h2 database for my sample application and I want to keep the data in the database file.
Does anybody know how I can achieve this?
My application is a spring boot application based on vaadin.

Thanks and kind regards,

Nullpointer

Comment: H2 is an in memory database dependent on the lifecycle of your application runtime. Therefore, when you deploy and have the application restart. Your database will also be wiped clean.

Comment: Thanks! On my local machine it is not cleaned. The database file is in the properties defined. This should also be after aws deployment.

Comment: My guess is that, AWS removes all local files each time you restart your app. Try to create a file and see if the file is retained after restart.

Comment: Could it also be a problem that I package it as a jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/src/main/resources/data/demo
```

probably does not exist on AWS because this is the directory on your local machine and you are deploying a JAR file.

Try to point to the user home like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/demo
```

But be aware that if BeansTalk will recreate the application the data may be lost.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this im the evening.